# Multiple plots in R with different settings for each axis with less lines of code

Tags: r, graph, legend, axis-labels

In the graph below,

- Is it possible to create same graph with less lines of codes? I mean, since each Figs. A-D has different label settings, I have to write settings for each Fig. which makes it longer.

The graph below is produced with the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dh536vqdegbm2w6/stackfig1_2.csv) in pdf device.
Any help with these issues is highly appreciated.(Newbie to R!). Since all the code is too long to post here, I have posted a part relevant to the problem here for Fig.C

[image: Graph from R]

```
#FigC
label1=c(0,100,200,300)
plot(data$TimeVariable2C,data$Variable2C,axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="",xlim=c(0,24),
     ylim=c(0,2.4),xaxs="i",yaxs="i",pch=19)
lines(data$TimeVariable3C,data$Variable3C)
axis(2,tick=T,at=seq(0.0,2.4,by=0.6),label= seq(0.0,2.4,by=0.6))
axis(1,tick=T,at=seq(0,24,by=6),label=seq(0,24,by=6))
mtext("(C)",side=1,outer=F,line=-10,adj=0.8)
minor.tick(nx=5,ny=5)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(data$TimeVariable1C,data$Variable1C,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="",type="l",
     ylim=c(800,0),xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
axis(3,xlim=c(0,24),tick=TRUE,at= seq(0,24,by=6),label=seq(0,24,by=6),col.axis="violetred4",col="violetred4")
axis(4,tick=TRUE,at= label1,label=label1,col.axis="violetred4",col="violetred4")
polygon(data$TimeVariable1C,data$Variable1C,col='violetred4',border=NA)
```

Comment: Consider making your question reproducible and perhaps split it into several smaller individual questions.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have separated the OP into 3 posts ( this and 2 [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127645/multiple-plots-in-r-with-both-primary-and-secondary-axes-on-all-4-sides-with-cus) [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128073/legend-in-multiple-plot-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask many questions in the same OP. I will try to answer to just one : How to simplify your code or rather how to call it once for each letter. I think it is better to put your data in the long format. For example, This will create a list of 4 elements

```
ll <- lapply(LETTERS[1:4],function(let){
  dat.let <- dat[,grepl(let,colnames(dat))]
  dd <- reshape(dat.let,direction ='long',
                v.names=c('TimeVariable','Variable'),
                varying=1:6)
  dd$time <- factor(dd$time)
  dd$Type <- let
  dd
}
)
```

ll is a list of 4 data.frame, where each one that looks like :

```
head(ll[[1]])
 time TimeVariable Variable id Type
1.1    1            0        0  1    A
2.1    1            0        5  2    A
3.1    1            8      110  3    A
4.1    1           16        0  4    A
5.1    1           NA       NA  5    A
6.1    1           NA       NA  6    A
```

Then you can use it like this for example :

library(Hmisc)

```
layout(matrix(1:4, 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
lapply(ll,function(data){
  label1=c(0,100,200,300)
  Type <- unique(dat$Type)
  dat <- subset(data,time==2)
  x.mm <- max(dat$Variable,na.rm=TRUE)
  plot(dat$TimeVariable,dat$Variable,axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="",xlim=c(0,x.mm),
       ylim=c(0,2.4),xaxs="i",yaxs="i",pch=19)
  dat <- subset(data,time==2)
  lines(dat$TimeVariable,dat$Variable)
  axis(2,tick=T,at=seq(0.0,2.4,by=0.6),label= seq(0.0,2.4,by=0.6))
  axis(1,tick=T,at=seq(0,x.mm,by=6),label=seq(0,x.mm,by=6))
  mtext(Type,side=1,outer=F,line=-10,adj=0.8)
  minor.tick(nx=5,ny=5)
  par(new=TRUE)
  dat <- subset(data,time==1)
  plot(dat$TimeVariable,dat$Variable,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="",type="l",
       ylim=c(800,0),xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
  axis(3,xlim=c(0,24),tick=TRUE,at= seq(0,24,by=6),label=seq(0,24,by=6),col.axis="violetred4",col="violetred4")
  axis(4,tick=TRUE,at= label1,label=label1,col.axis="violetred4",col="violetred4")
  polygon(dat$TimeVariable,dat$Variable,col='violetred4',border=NA)
})
```

Another advantage of using the long data format is to use ``ggplot2`and`facet_wrap` for example .

```
 ## transform your data to a data.frame
 dat.l <- do.call(rbind,ll)
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(subset(dat.l,time !=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=TimeVariable,y=Variable,group=time,color=time))+
  geom_polygon(data=subset(dat.l,time ==1),
              aes(x=TimeVariable,y=60-Variable/10,fill=Type))+
  geom_line(data=subset(dat.l,time ==1),
               aes(x=TimeVariable,y=Variable,fill=Type))+
  facet_wrap(~Type,scales='free')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, creating data frame works great for minimizing lines of code. Even though graph from ggplot looks great, I couldn't use it, since it does not support secondary axes (side=3 and 4).

Comment: @maxm yes very hard to get secondary axesusing ggplot2. I think you will have more chances using `lattice` in this case.