# Multiple plots in R with both primary and secondary axes on all 4 sides with custom axis label

Tags: r, graph, axis-labels

According to the comments from others, this post has been separated into smaller questions from the previous version of this  [OP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121390/multiple-plots-in-r-with-different-settings-for-each-axis-with-less-lines-of-cod)

In the graph below, will you help me to

- Close the side=4 (in each Figs. A-D), keeping the labels as it is (to the length as shown) and create minor ticks at secondary axes (side=3 and 4); no.of div=5.
- Why does minor.tick(nx=5,ny=5) produce 6 division in tick for Fig.C

The graph below is produced with the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dh536vqdegbm2w6/stackfig1_2.csv) in pdf device.
Any help with these issues is highly appreciated.(Newbie to R!) Since all the code is too long to post here, I have posted a part relevant to the problem here for Fig.C

[image: Graph from R]

```
#FigC
label1=c(0,100,200,300)
plot(data$TimeVariable2C,data$Variable2C,axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="",xlim=c(0,24),
     ylim=c(0,2.4),xaxs="i",yaxs="i",pch=19)
lines(data$TimeVariable3C,data$Variable3C)
axis(2,tick=T,at=seq(0.0,2.4,by=0.6),label= seq(0.0,2.4,by=0.6))
axis(1,tick=T,at=seq(0,24,by=6),label=seq(0,24,by=6))
mtext("(C)",side=1,outer=F,line=-10,adj=0.8)
minor.tick(nx=5,ny=5)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(data$TimeVariable1C,data$Variable1C,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="",type="l",
     ylim=c(800,0),xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
axis(3,xlim=c(0,24),tick=TRUE,at= seq(0,24,by=6),label=seq(0,24,by=6),col.axis="violetred4",col="violetred4")
axis(4,tick=TRUE,at= label1,label=label1,col.axis="violetred4",col="violetred4")
polygon(data$TimeVariable1C,data$Variable1C,col='violetred4',border=NA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `minor.tick` produces 6 intervals is that it was written on the assumption that the default axis divisions would be used. It has no way of knowing that you substituted a different major tick placement.

After each axis(4, ...) call, you should make a call:

```
 box()
```

I already answered the question yesterday on SO about how to construct a modified version of `minor.tick` that could be used with side =3 or =4.

Comment: Thanks, box() works for closing the axis. Yes, modified version of minor.tick works for side=3 or 4 with default axis division. Thank you for that. However, like you said it does not work for different major division (like the case in Fig. C, side=1,2) and it also does not work for side=4 (Fig. A-D), where I want the major tick and minor tick only up to certain length of the axis (up to 300 in this case). Any advice?

Comment: Rewriting a `majorminor` function with using the parameters of both `axis` and `minor.tick` initial calls to `axis` and subsequent a call to suitably modified code pulled from `minor.tick` would seem the way to go.