# Legend in multiple plot in R

Tags: r, graph, axis-labels

According to the comments from others, this post has been separated into several 
[smaller questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127645/multiple-plots-in-r-with-both-primary-and-secondary-axes-on-all-4-sides-with-cus) from the previous version of this  [OP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121390/multiple-plots-in-r-with-different-settings-for-each-axis-with-less-lines-of-cod)

In the graph below, will you help me to (Newbie to R)

- Custom legends according to the data they represent like filled for variable 1, circle points for variable 2 and line for variable 3 and their colors.
- same letter size for the legend and axis-names.

The graph below is produced with the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dh536vqdegbm2w6/stackfig1_2.csv) in pdf device with following layout.

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,3,4,5),nrow = 3,ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE)
layout(mat = m,heights = c(0.47,0.06,0.47))
par(mar=c(4,4.2,3,4.2))

#Codes for Fig A and B
...

#Margin for legend
par(mar = c(0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1))
    # Code for legend
...

#Codes for Fig C and D
...
```

[image: Graph from R]

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer (at least a tested one) without code that produces a 2 x 2 layout. I also do not see what "Variable 1 and "Variable 2" or "their colors" are referring to.

Comment: @maxm maybe it is better to use the data in the long format as I showed you in a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121390/multiple-plots-in-r-with-different-settings-for-each-axis-with-less-lines-of-cod/17126387#17126387). I is easy to use variable *time* to set legends and data shapes.

Comment: @DWin I agree with you on the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dh536vqdegbm2w6/stackfig1_2.csv)  and [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121390/multiple-plots-in-r-with-different-settings-for-each-axis-with-less-lines-of-cod).

Comment: @agstudy Yes, I found long format useful in multi plot graphs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using   `doubleYScale` from `latticeExtra` and the data in the long format (see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121390/multiple-plots-in-r-with-different-settings-for-each-axis-with-less-lines-of-cod/17126387#17126387)), you can simplify the work:

1. No need to create a custom layout to superpose many plots
2. No need to create the legend manually

[image]

The idea is to create 2 separates objects and then merge them using `doubleYScale`. The latter will create the second axes. I hope I get your ploygon idea since it is not very clear why do you invert it in your OP.

```
library(latticeExtra)
obj1 <- xyplot(Variable~TimeVariable|Type,type='l',
               groups=time,               scales=list(x=list(relation='free'),
                                                      y=list(relation='free')),
               auto.key=list(columns = 3,lines = TRUE,points=FALSE) ,

       data = subset(dat.l,time !=1))
obj2 <- xyplot(Variable~TimeVariable|Type,
               data = subset(dat.l,time ==1),type='l',
               scales=list(x=list(alternating=2),
                           auto.key=list(columns = 3,lines = TRUE,points=FALSE),
                           y=list(relation='free')),
               panel=function(x,y,...){
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
         panel.polygon(x,y,col='violetred4',border=NA,alpha=0.3)
               })


doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.axis = TRUE,style1 = 0, style2 = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for another way for plotting. However I want to plot similar graph as in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

**1) For the legend part**

The data can be found on https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kgq8tyvuvq22ym/stackfig1_2.csv

The code I used is as follows:

```
data <- read.csv("stackfig1_2.csv")
library(Hmisc)

label1=c(0,100,200,300)
plot(data$TimeVariable2C,data$Variable2C,axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="",xlim=c(0,24),
     ylim=c(0,2.4),xaxs="i",yaxs="i",pch=19)
lines(data$TimeVariable3C,data$Variable3C)
axis(2,tick=T,at=seq(0.0,2.4,by=0.6),label= seq(0.0,2.4,by=0.6))
axis(1,tick=T,at=seq(0,24,by=6),label=seq(0,24,by=6))
mtext("(C)",side=1,outer=F,line=-10,adj=0.8)
minor.tick(nx=5,ny=5)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(data$TimeVariable1C,data$Variable1C,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="",type="l",
     ylim=c(800,0),xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
axis(3,xlim=c(0,24),tick=TRUE,at= seq(0,24,by=6),label=seq(0,24,by=6),col.axis="violetred4",col="violetred4")
axis(4,tick=TRUE,at= label1,label=label1,col.axis="violetred4",col="violetred4")
polygon(data$TimeVariable1C,data$Variable1C,col='violetred4',border=NA)


legend("top", legend = c("Variable A","Variable B","Variable C"), col = c("black","violetred4","black"),
       ncol = 2, lwd =c("","",2),pch=c(19,15,NA),cex=1)
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

2) To make the font size same use the parameter `cex` and make it same everywhere.

Comment: legend format works great. However cex=1 was given in both legend and axis name in the above graph but the text size still appears to be different. I guess cex is a relative parameter. I also checked (text size = ps*cex). I have different height settings for row of plot and legend and par(mar) is also different. May be these settings are responsible somehow.

Comment: @maxm: make sure you use `cex.axis` to control axis tick label text size, and `cex.lab` to control axis label text size.